# ActiveResource vs HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource, httparty

I'm moving our primary datastore away from ActiveRecord, and instead the data will be accessible through a REST api as JSON. Should I use ActiveResource or HTTParty to access the data?  It's primarily going to be read-only for view rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that HTTParty has a better API, is better maintained and more flexible than ActiveResource. I would use HTTParty.